# Show two random variables have the same distribution?

Tags: random-variables

I need help with this question. Thanks :-)! :

Assume that X is uniform on $[0, 1]$ and that $F$ is the cdf of a continuous random
variable Y . 
Show that  $Z = F^{−1}(X)$ has the same distribution as $Y$ .

(Note: $X$ uniform
on $[a, b]$ means that for any $x \in [a, b]\,\; Pr(X ≤ x) = \frac {(x − a)}
{(b − a)}$

Comment: You mean F inverse ?

Comment: Yes. F inverse, so I guess that would mean the quantile function of the random variable Y.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To demonstrate that $F^{-1}(X)$ and $Y$ are identically distributed, you need to show that: $$\mathsf P(F^{-1}(X)\leq z) = \mathsf P(Y\leq z)$$

You know that $X\sim\mathcal{U}[0;1]$ so then, $\;\mathsf P(X\leq x) = x\;\mathbf 1_{x\in[0;1]}\;$.

And also that the CDF of $Y$ is $\;F(y)\mathop{:=}\mathsf P(Y\leq y) \;$ and $\;F(y)\in[0;1]\;$.

That should get you started.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot.